# Incrementing a unique return value from a mapping

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-721, mapping

Let's say I have a mapping called Tries. each time a function is called I want to increment the return value from 0 to x depending on the number of tries (trying to call the function).
here's the mapping:

```
mapping(uint256 => uint256) public Tries;
```

and here's the function:

```
function Unlock(uint256 tokenId, string memory _answer) public {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "you are not the owner!");
        Tries[tokenId] = ???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in this way:

```
function Unlock(uint256 tokenId) public {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "you are not the owner!");
        uint x = Tries[tokenId];
        Tries[tokenId] = x+1;
}
```

You resume the attempts last value from the mapping with this line of code: `int x = Tries[tokenId]`. And then increment the current value **+1** (or another number) for each attempts.

Comment: Works exactly as intended! Thank you.